# I would like to store returning visitors in a GDPR compliant way, using the local storage

Tags: php, cookies, local-storage, analytics, gdprconsentform

Without storing any personal data about the visitor, I'd like to store the fact a visitor came back on a specific page on my website, for my own analysis.

I would store the following fact in in the database of my website:

```
Timestamp
PageURL
Returning visitor: yes/no
```

How can that be done in a GPDR compliant way? I don't want to identify the visitor, only the behaviour. My idea is to use the local storage to store the list of pages the user has already visited, and send an ajax request on a page load which would cary the following info: "this page has been visited by a returning visitor (or not)".

Is that feasible without notice or consent? AFAIK, no personal data about the visitor would be stored on my own server.

Comment: We're not lawyers, so I'm not sure whether anyone is going to comment to say whether you're complying with a specific piece of legislation or not, and I wouldn't necessarily trust the answer if they did. Consult a lawyer who specialises in this legislation and also understands technology.

Comment: I don't think this is a GDPR issue, but I think it's a cookie consent issue. Related, but not the same. This would count as a first-party tracking/performance/marketing cookie of some kind, and you'd likely have to obtain users' consent to be tracked via it.

Comment: However from a purely technical point of view, I'm not sure localstorage necessarily works...but it probably depends how you define "user" and "returning"...many people, me included, frequently "return" to a website using a different device or browser than the one we used last to visit it an earlier time. If you're authenticating your users, then you can identify them easily no matter where they access the site from. If you're not, then yeah you could potentially do something based on the local browser. I'm not going to comment on the legality, as previously mentioned.

Comment: Another aside - there are probably plenty of analytics packages (some free) which already do this kind of thing for you much more neatly, and with more features.

Comment: GPDR compliancy hinges more on disclosure, not technicalities or consent/nag screens.

Comment: @ADyson, indeed, multiple solutions exists already, my attempt at doing it is for educational purpose. For my use case, i don't want to authenticate users, only track visits, and visits from returning visitors. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @mario: but what would you disclose for such a case, as no personal data is stored on the server-side? Thanks

Comment: @ceejayoz but if the end goal is not to track the user or its personal data, but only the visit itself, how is it impacting the privacy of the user?

Comment: Well, this sounds like something  you can *proudly* note in the imprint. If it amounts to a individual user counter, without privacy concerns, just make a note/list there (localstorage | user counter | no personally identifiable details recorded).

Comment: https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-pecr/cookies-and-similar-technologies/ - as far as I will go on the legal front is to say that I think ceejayoz is right, you're confusing the GDPR and the separate regulations on cookies (and related technologies which store data on the user's machine, such as localstorage), which are not related to personal data directly but more about general tracking. You're creating the ability to track the device (and thus potentially the individual) even if currently you don't intend to transmit info about the device. The user should be aware of that.

Comment: @ADyson : Thanks for your reply. I think indeed I am confusing both. I will check the regulation on cookies then. :)

Comment: @LaetitiaDallinge GDPR deals with personal data. You're correct that this doesn't contain PII. It is a tracking cookie, though, and *that* is still something you have to disclose separately.